# Qt Use QTabBar in a Different QLayout

Tags: qt, layout, move, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I have a custom QTabWidget and a custom QTabBar. Everything is working fine and I can go through the tabs and stuff. But the thing is, I wanna put the QTabBar in a different layout than the QTabWidget. This way I can make a Menu Bar type of layout where I have the tabs and a couple differnt QPushButtons next to it all going left to right in the same row aligned.

So, basically can I move the QTabBar into a separate QHBoxLayout or QGridLayout away from the tab widget, but keep the functionality?

Comment: You can treat `QTabBar` as a widget and place it in any layout you want. Its functionality does not depend on where it is placed.

Comment: Ok well I guess I should've mentioned this in the question as well. I have already placed it in a separate layout but once I click a tab, the tab bar moves back to position and I don't know why.

Comment: Ok nevermind I got it to stop moving now. Thanks allot!

Comment: One more thing I have a HUGE margin above the tab widget now. You know how I can get rid of that?

Comment: I do not see the layout, but you can try to play with `QLayout::setContentsMargins()` and `QWidget::setContentsMargins()`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and then I tried some css but nope.